# How to achieve buffering logic with publish sequence in RxJava2?

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I want to achieve the following with RxJava and as I may not have enough knowledge in this area would like to have some help :)

I need to create a PublishSubject which would emit events with the following sequence:

- Emit 1, 2, 3
- Buffer 4 in subscribe's completion if a certain condition is not satisfied (may be a network connection for example or some other condition).
- For 5, 6 ... buffer after 4 if the condition is not satisfied yet.
- Repeat to emit 4 after some time when the condition is satisfied.
- If trying to emit 5,6 and the condition is satisfied, then instead of buffering 5, 6 ... after 4, just emit 4 and then 5, 6, 7 , 8 ...

The last 2 points are necessary because the sequence of emitting is really important, which makes difficulties  for me to achieve to this.

I hope I could describe what I want to achieve :)

**Findings:** After asking this question I've done some findings and achieved the following:

```
private Observable observable = publishSubject
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map(Manager::callNew)
        .doOnError(throwable -> Logger.e(throwable, "Error occurred"))
        .retryWhen(throwableObservable -> throwableObservable
                .zipWith(Observable.range(1, 10), (n, i) -> i)
                .flatMap(retryCount -> {
                    long retrySeconds = (long) Math.pow(2, retryCount);
                    Logger.d("The call has been failed retrying in %s seconds. Retry count %s", retrySeconds, retryCount);
                    return Observable.timer(retrySeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .doOnNext(aLong -> {
                                C24Logger.d("Timer was completed. %s", aLong);
                            })
                            .doOnComplete(() -> Logger.d("Timer was completed."));
                }));
```

The problem is here with PublishSubject. Because it already has emitted all the items, it emits only new ones for retryWhen. If I use ReplaySubject them it emits also the old completed items too for the new retryWhen re-subscribe, which I do not need anymore.

**Is there a way to use the ReplaySubject to remove the completed items from the buffer?**

Answer (score 0):

You want to be able to turn buffering on and off, depending upon an external condition. Perhaps the simplest way to do it is use the `buffer()` operator to continually buffer items based on the condition.

(I have removed stuff from the observer chain)

```
private Observable observable = publishSubject
      .publish( obs -> obs.buffer( obs.filter( v -> externalCondition( v ) ) ) )
      .flatMapIterable( bufferedList -> bufferedList )
      .subscribe( ... );
```

The `publish()` operator allows multiple observer chains to subscribe to the incoming observer chain. The `buffer()` operator monitors the observable that emits a value only when the external condition is true.

When the external condition is true, `buffer()` will emit a series of lists with only a single element. When the condition goes false, `buffer()` starts buffering up the results, and when the condition goes true again, all the buffered items are emitted as a list. The `flatMapIterable()` step will take each item out of the buffer and emit it separately.